# Debugging VBA copy range and saving using cell references as file name

Tags: excel, vba

I've researched a great bit on stackoverflow and mrexcel and a few other sites to come up with this.  In short I have a template that I copy information into to combine with a few variables to create a text string that populates into a range that I've named 'export'.  I would like for this range to be copied to a new workbook to be saved as a .txt file.  However, I want the VBA to name and save the file to a predetermined location [t:\downloads]. The file name should be a combination from two cells on the source sheet the account number (stored in cell c1) and the month/year (stored in cell b3).  For example, if the account number in cell c1 is 123456 and the date in b3 is 12/25/2017, then I would like the filename to appear as t:\downloads\123456.2017.12.txt.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
Sub Foo_Tab()
  Dim wbSource As Workbook
  Dim wssource As Worksheet
  Dim wbdest As Workbook


'References
  Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
  Set wssource = ActiveSheet
  Set wbdest = Workbooks.Add
  acct = Cells("c1")
  yr = Year(Cells("b3"))
  mnth = Month(Cells("b3"))


'Copy range on original sheet
  wssource.Range("Export").Copy

'Save in new workbook
  wbdest.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

'get file name from cells
  Dim path As String
  Dim full As String
  Dim acct As String
  Dim yr As String
  Dim mnth As String
  path = "Z:\Downloads\"
  full = path + acct + "." + yr + "." + mnth + ".txt"
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=full
  wbdest.Close savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't say what the actual problem is, but I suspect it's here `Cells`. First, you can't call a range reference inside `Cells`. `Cells` expects (row, column) arguments in numerical form.... ie. `Cells(1,3)`. Use `Range` to use cell address: `Range("C1")`. Second, qualify every reference to `Cells` or `Range` with it's parent workbook. For example, `wbSource.Cells(1,3)`. As it's written the code is looking at the newly added workbook to gather the data from cells, which will obviously be blank.

Comment: Make sure you include `FileFormat:= xlTextWindows` in the `.SaveAs` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
ActiveWorbook.SaveAs filename:=full
wbdest.Close savechanges:=True
```

with this (I assume that wbdest is active worbook; -4158 is for .txt format):

```
With wbdest
        .SaveAs full, FileFormat:=-4158
        .Close SaveChanges:=True
End With
```